# How to fix "Apache is not running"

Tags: apache2, lamp

i installed xampp in my ubuntu 12.04. but Apache was not running. like this:

```
$ sudo lampp status
Version: XAMPP for Linux 1.5.5a
Apache is not running.
MySQL is running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

then after i had typed:

```
tail -2 /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
```

it showed me some errors:

```
[Mon Mar 09 21:32:59 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Mar 09 21:32:59 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
```

Comment: These are just warnings not errors. Anyway - try to restart apache/httpd manually separately to see what might be actual issue, if any. If necessary review apache's config.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `service apache2 start` in order to start Apache? The warnings shown in the log are just this, warnings. Apache should also start with these warnings.